# Can programs in SSA form lead to the construction of cyclic SDG?

Tags: dependencies, compiler-construction, graph-theory, compiler-optimization, ssa

Variables in [Static Single Assignment (SSA) form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form) transformed programs are only assigned once. This is done by making up a new version of a variable for each variable that is assigned more than once.
Now, if I use the SSA transformed program to construct the [System Dependence Graph (SDG)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/77606.77608), can it have any cycles? such as:
A -> B -> ... -> A, where each "->" represents a control/data dependency.

I just wonder if there is a possibility that the generated SDG graph can include cycles since it is constructed to represent a program in SSA form, which writes to a program variable only once. I am also worried about function calls and their control edges in the SDG graph. If you think cycles are possible, then I would really appreciate an example of this case. Thank you.